# Pinia getter does not filter state (options API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a pinia store I am using with a vue component, with the options API. I have a getter in my pinia store that is supposed doing some basic filtering of items. However, the getter just returns what is in state without any of the filtering applied.

My component:

```
<template>
   <DetailsWrapper :filteredDetails="filteredDetails"
</template>
<script>
   import {mapState, } from 'pinia';
   export default {
      components: DetailsWrapper,
      computed: {
        ...mapState(useDetailsStore, {
           filteredDetails: store => store.filteredDetails,
      },
    };
</script>
```

In my pinia store I have:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const useDetailsStore = defineStore('details', {
    getters: {
       filteredDetails: state => {
       const productDetails = state.product && state.product.details;
       productDetails.forEach(detail => {
             detail.values.filter(detail => detail.isOnline && detail.isDisplayable
       });
       return productDetails
    },
});
export default useDetailsStore
```

The end result is just that everything in `productDetails` is returned -- nothing is filtered out, even though there are definitely values to be filtered.

If anyone could provide any guidance it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Nothing is updated in your code because `.filter` does not mutate the original property. Rather it *returns array items that match criteria identified in the callback*. Further, the result of your `.filter` calls is not assigned to anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

const useDetailsStore = defineStore('details', {
  getters: 
  {
     filteredDetails(state)
     {
       return (state.product?.details || []).map(product => ({
         ...product,
         values: product.values.filter(val => val.isOnline && val.isDisplayable),
       });
    },
});

export default useDetailsStore;
```